# problem with running eslint with npm node js

Tags: node.js, npm, eslint

> eslint . --ext .js

Error: .eslintrc:
Environment key "es2021" is unknown

```
at Object.keys.forEach.id (Image api/node_modules/eslint/lib/shared/config-validator.js:169:19)
at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
at validateEnvironment (Image api/node_modules/eslint/lib/shared/config-validator.js:163:30)
at validateConfigArray (Image api/node_modules/eslint/lib/shared/config-validator.js:334:9)
at CascadingConfigArrayFactory._finalizeConfigArray (Image api/node_modules/eslint/lib/cli-engine/cascading-config-array-factory.js:417:13)
at CascadingConfigArrayFactory.getConfigArrayForFile (Image api/node_modules/eslint/lib/cli-engine/cascading-config-array-factory.js:271:21)
at FileEnumerator._iterateFilesRecursive (Image api/node_modules/eslint/lib/cli-engine/file-enumerator.js:396:49)
at _iterateFilesRecursive.next (<anonymous>)
at FileEnumerator.iterateFiles (Image api/node_modules/eslint/lib/cli-engine/file-enumerator.js:251:49)
at iterateFiles.next (<anonymous>)
```

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 2
npm ERR! image-api@1.0.0 lint: `eslint . --ext .js`
npm ERR! Exit status 2
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the image-api@1.0.0 lint script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/marwan/.npm/_logs/2022-01-10T23_00_43_567Z-debug.log

**.**eslintrc****

{
"env": {
"browser": true,
"es2021": true
},
"parser": "@typescript-eslint/parser",
"parserOptions": {
"ecmaVersion": 12,
"sourceType": "module"
},
"plugins": [
"@typescript-eslint"
],
"rules": {
"indent": [
"error",
2
],
"linebreak-style": [
"error",
"unix"
],
"quotes": [
"error",
"single"
],
"semi": [
"error",
"always"
],
"no-multiple-empty-lines": [
2,
{ "max": 1, "maxEOF": 0, "maxBOF": 0 }
],
"no-trailing-spaces": "error",
"import/no-extraneous-dependencies": 0
}
}

Comment: Can you show us your `.eslintrc.json` config file please. Or alternatively whichever config file format you chose. `config-validator.js` is throwing an error implying there is an error in your configuration

Comment: the ask edited with eslintrc code

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

The environment [`es2021`](https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring/language-options#specifying-environments) was added with ESLint 8 (ESLint 7 [does not have it](https://eslint.org/docs/7.0.0/user-guide/configuring#specifying-environments)). The error message is a hint that you are using an older version of ESLint.

Look into your package.json, update the ESLint version to >= 8, then run `npm install`.

Comment: I'm using eslint 8.4.0

Comment: @marwanAhmed I doubt that. Looking at your stack trace, an error is thrown in config-validator.js on line 169 for the code `Object.keys.forEach.id`, but in ESLint 8.4.0 that code is on line 176: https://github.com/eslint/eslint/blob/v8.4.0/lib/shared/config-validator.js#L169-L176